# How to combine 2 different integers to create a single float (or a double)

Tags: objective-c

I'm Cesare from Italy (please excuse my english), this is my first question posted on StackOverflow and I'm pretty new to Objective-C... I hope I won't make a mess on my first try.

**I would like to "combine" two integers that I already have to create a new float (or a double).**

By "combine", I mean that I'd like to have the first int before the point and the second int after the point, I'm not trying to convert from int to float. Maybe an example could explain better what I'm trying to do:

**First int: 7**

**Second int: 92**

**The float I'm trying to get: 7.92**

I looked for a previous question like mine but I haven't found anything, maybe because what I'm trying to do is pretty dumb (I have a UIPickerView with 2 components, each containing hundreds of integers, and I'm trying to create a float or double variable that has the selection of the first component before the point and the selection of the second component after the point).

Thanks in advance for your help,

Cesare

Comment: what did you try? this sounds like pretty basic math.

Comment: Is it possible to produce a number such as 7.09? Or do you not need to be able to obtain such numbers from your input?

Comment: user3477950 Before posting here, I tried to combine the number in a string and converting that string back to number, but it sounded an awful hack... your solution is perfect for me, thanks!   David K No, I don't need to have numbers beginning with 0 after the decimal point. Thanks!

Comment: Then you have asked the right question and gotten a good answer, so all is well.

Comment: @DavidK My experience with StackOverflow is already very positive indeed. I can't imagine how much harder was learning to code before StackOverflow and Google (which usually sends me here anyway...). Very nice community and service, this is the first time for me to ask a question, but I've already been helped so many times by previous questions... All is well, have a nice evening!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just think about what the definition and/or the purpose of the decimal point is. It separates the part of the number which is less than one from the part greater than or equal to one.

So, keep dividing the part after the decimal point until it's less than 1:

```
int firstPart = 7;
int secondPart = 92; // or whatever


float f = secondPart;

while (f >= 1) {
    f /= 10;
}

f += firstPart;
```

Comment: Not necessarily the fastest method, but it is clear and direct.

Comment: @DavidK exactly. it doesn't sound like OP would be looking for a "fast" method, since it seems this is going to be GUI code. Anyway, I'm not sure how this could be implemented more efficiently. The only other approach I can think of is determining the order of magnitude of the second part and dividing by it, but that involves logarithms, and I'm pretty sure that would be a lot slower than a loop with a few comparisons.

Comment: The answer provided by @user3477950 works just fine for me, thank you very much. It's indeed GUI code, so I don't need a faster method and logarithms are out of my league for now... Thanks again!

Comment: @user3477950 sorry, I accepted your answer but I can't yet upvote and I really wanted to thank you because the problem is maybe trivial, but I've spent the last hour trying to figure it out.

Comment: +1 from me anyway. You can (possibly) make it more efficient by doing a kind of "binary search" on the order of magnitude within some range, but that depends on the nature of the input and is unnecessarily complicated for this application.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is later, but came across a similar situation. Maybe this is more efficient.

Take the second number, 92 and divide it by 100. That gives you .92. Add that to the first number. That can give you 7.92. However, since you're adding integers that you want converted to a float, you'll need to cast the numbers when adding them. Like this:

```
int firstPart = 7;
int secondPart = 92;

float afterDecimalPlace = (float)secondPart/100.0;

float numberAsFloat = (float)firstPart + afterDecimalPlace;
```

essentially that is:
92/100 = .92

7 + .92 = 7.92